# JpaRepository - Inner Join - Subsequent selects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm facing a problem when I try to get an list of ServiceCup with its ServiceLanguage. When I try to manipulate the list of ServiceCup in my service layer hibernate is executing a second query and populate my ServiceCup with all ServiceLanguage again.

ServiceCup x ServiceLanguage x LanguageCup

**ServiceCup:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "csm_service")
public class ServiceCup extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String context;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to CsmServiceLanguage
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "service")
    private List<ServiceLanguage> serviceLanguages;

}
```

**ServiceLanguage:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "csm_service_language")
public class ServiceLanguage extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "translated_name")
    private String translatedName;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to CsmLanguage
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "csm_language_id_fk")
    private LanguageCup language;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to CsmService
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "csm_service_id_fk")
    private ServiceCup service;

}
```

**JpaRepository:**

```
    @Query(value = "select s, sl from ServiceCup s \n" + "INNER JOIN FETCH ServiceLanguage sl on s.id = sl.service \n"
            + "where sl.language.id = :languageId")
    List<ServiceCup> findAllServicesByLanguageId(@Param("languageId") String languageId);
```

**Query in repository layer:**

```
select *all_fields* from csm_service servicecup0_ inner join csm_service_language servicelan1_ on (servicecup0_.id=servicelan1_.csm_service_id_fk) where servicelan1_.csm_language_id_fk=?
```

But in service layer execute a lot of queries to bring all the relations of ServiceCup. I want the ServiceCup objects populate but only with the results that are in the query.

*How can I get a ServiceCup object with only the results of the query?*

PS: In my method in service layer I have **@Transactional(readOnly = true)** but if I remove I can't get the objects related to ServiceCup.

Comment: If you remove the sl from the select portion of the query `@Query(value = "select s from ServiceCup s \n" + "INNER JOIN FETCH ServiceLanguage sl on s.id = sl.service \n"
            + "where sl.language.id = :languageId")` does it exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: @HopeyOne But I need sl because languageId is not in ServiceCup.

Comment: You don't need to select an entity to use it in a join. The default `FetchType` for `OneToMany` is lazy, the default for `ManyToOne` is eager. I think selecting the ServiceLanguage even though you aren't returning it in the query method means that Hibernate will eager fetch every related entity for ServiceLanguage entities. You can still access the related ServiceLanguage entity from the ServiceCup even if they are not selected in the query and hibernate will load them automatically as required (lazy `FetchType`).

Comment: @HopeyOne how can I resolve to bring only what I want? ServiceCup with its related ServiceLanguage with that Id of LanguageCup?

Comment: What I have suggested is that you remove the "sl" from `select s, sl from ...` such that it reads `select s from ...` as your query method returns only  `List<ServiceCup>` ServiceLanguage "sl" does not need to be in the select part of the query. Give that a try, I believe that is why hibernate is performing additional queries.

Comment: No @HopeyOne. I need sl "where sl.language.id = :languageId"

Comment: Again, I'm not suggesting you remove sl from the `JOIN` or the `WHERE` clause, **only the SELECT**.

Comment: Didn't work @HopeyOne. In service layer all the queries are redone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use projection and not the entity to execute the query only once.

**ServiceCupProj**

```
public interface ServiceCupProj {

    public Long getId();

    public String getDescription();

    public String getInternalname();
......
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface CupServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceCup, Long> {

@Query(value = "select servicecup0_.id as id, servicelan1_.translated_description as description, servicelan1_.translated_name as internalname \n"
            + "from csm_service servicecup0_ inner join csm_service_language servicelan1_ on (servicecup0_.id=servicelan1_.csm_service_id_fk) \n"
            + "where servicelan1_.csm_language_id_fk = :languageId ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ServiceCupProj> findAllServicesByLanguageId(@Param("languageId") String languageId);
......
```

And in the service layer I transform this ServiceCupProj in the entity that I need.